# Output function results to multiple files in r?

Tags: r, loops, batch-processing, naming

I am trying to run a function on a batch of files within a directory, how can I write each output to a file that is named according to its origin? E.g:

```
files <- dir(pattern="*.csv")

for (i in 1:length(files)){
  dat<-reformat.funct(files[i])
  write.csv(dat, "???.reform.csv")
}
```

I would like to replace the "???" above with the i'th file name from "files."
Suggestions on more efficient ways to do it also welcome (for scripts longer than one line).

Thank you.

Comment: Note that if want you `dir` to return only files with names ending in the extension '.csv', your pattern should use `pattern='\\.csv$'`. In regex, `*` indicates "0 or more of the preceding character" and "." indicates "any character". Literal "." must be escaped with "\\", and "$" indicates end of string. Your pattern would also match against a file with the name "blahcsv.exe".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given `files`:

```
 out.files <- gsub("\\.csv$", ".reform.csv", files)
```

Comment: @sherminds - This could be implemented without the `for` loop as: `sapply(files, function(x) write.csv(reformat.funct(x), sub('\\.csv$', '.reform.csv', x)))`

Comment: @jbaums - Great, I was trying to figure out how to do this with sapply That was nearly magical, you should put it down as a response so I can accept it.

Comment: @Ricardo_Saporta - this produces a list of the new file names, but does not output renamed files into the directory. How does it integrate with object _dat_ and `write.csv`?

Comment: @sherminds I won't add it as an answer, since the crux of it is given by Ricardo. However, to answer your question, using Ricardo's suggestion and your `for` loop, simply use `write.csv(dat, out.files[i])`.